# Download large files in iOS

Tags: ios

I wish to download large file (about: 500MB) from server.
The server is implemented by us server with gRPC command that works as follows. The user request for file and then the app receives byte stream which added to file.
In Android I am using **background persistent notification with service**, and opening new thread on this service until the download completes. The user can exit the app and the OS will not kill persistent notification service.

What is the equivalent for background downloading for iOS. I checked the [URLSessionDownloadTask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondownloadtask) but I do not think it will work with gRPC.

What is your solution for downloading big data with iOS?

Comment: Use background `URLSessionConfiguration` for your own `URLSession` using that `URLSessionDownloadTask` with HTTP request. See [Downloading Files in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_in_the_background/).

Comment: To the best of my knowledge `URLSessionDownloadTask` is the only option. I cannot think of anything else that would work in the background. But as you have already figured out, it only works with *https* URLs. Can you change your server somehow, e.g. the gRPC command returns a unique one-time URL, which can then be used by `URLSessionDownloadTask`?

Comment: Apart from trying to execute a long running operation, I think you should make the download resumable. Which means the app should be able to continue download from the last position when the app made foreground again.